# How can I automate Google app with Appium?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

Can I automate Google apps with Android (etc. Google Keep)? I got assignment to write a code with Appium, but I thought we need debug version of apk to automate it.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: You do not need a debug version of the apk. The release will do too

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. Most of the standard Android apps can be automated with Appium, and Google Keep is one of them. Assuming you have the app already installed on your device, you need the following capabilities to launch it:

```
{
  "deviceName": "Samsung S8",
  "platformVersion": "9.0",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appPackage": "com.google.android.keep",
  "appActivity": "com.google.android.apps.keep.ui.activities.BrowseActivity",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator2"
}
```

Once it launched, you can observe DOM and get the required locators.

Hope this helps.